# Append link to href from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Can anyone explain to me how can I append the `link` from JSON file to `a href`? I could grab the images but I have no idea how to get the links.

This is my code that I am using

```
<body style="background: #e5e5e5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <a href="">
                        <div class="cover" id="img"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        var data = {
            "info": [{
                "cover": "highlighted/1.gif",
                "link":"http://google.com"
            },
            {
                "cover": "highlighted/1.gif",
                "link":"http://google.com"
            }]
        };
        data.info.forEach( function(obj) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = obj.cover;
            document.getElementById("img").appendChild(img);
        });
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: You are after jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: every image tag should be under a tag?Im correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: `<a>` is an inline element, you should put it in the div.

Here is a working code:

```
<body style="background: #e5e5e5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="cover" id="img">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var data = {
        "info": [{
            "cover": "highlighted/1.gif",
        "link":"http://google.com/1"
        },
        {
            "cover": "highlighted/2.gif",
        "link":"http://google.com/2"
        }]
    };
    var imagesBlock = document.getElementById("img");
    data.info.forEach( function(obj) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = obj.cover;
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.setAttribute('href', obj.link);
        a.appendChild(img);
        imagesBlock.appendChild(a);

    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Here is another version, where we clone a DOM tree instead,, following discussion (see below):

```
<body style="background: #e5e5e5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="repeatingImages">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="cover">
                    <a><img /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var data = {
        "info": [{
            "cover": "highlighted/1.gif",
        "link":"http://google.com/1"
        },
        {
            "cover": "highlighted/2.gif",
        "link":"http://google.com/2"
        }]
    };

    var repeatingImages = document.getElementById("repeatingImages");

    // get the template block, clone and remove the source
    var blockTemplate = repeatingImages.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].cloneNode(true);
    repeatingImages.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].remove();

    data.info.forEach( function(obj) {
        block = blockTemplate.cloneNode(true);
        block.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute('href', obj.link);
        block.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].setAttribute('src', obj.cover);
        repeatingImages.appendChild(block);

    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This is working but one thing. There is going to display everything in cover class and it will not gonna create multiple class col-sm-4

Comment: Indeed! If that's what you want, you might go at it differently.

I would then use `sourceDiv.cloneNode();` to copy the tree of nodes as many times you need (div > div > a > img).

If you do that, take into account the in HTML ids are supposed to be unique, so you would have to remove id="img" from your code.

I'll update my answer with the changes you need.

Comment: What do you mean by differently?

Comment: There you go, added the second solution. What I have to suggest, though, is to consider using a framework rather than bare JS for this kind of stuff. There are really loads of frameworks is JS and you *will* find one that suits your project.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are after this?

All you need to do is:

- Create a link element and assign href to it
- Create an img element and assign src to it
- Append img element to the link element
- Append link to the target div

```js
var data = {
    "info": [{
        "cover": "highlighted/1.gif",
        "link":"http://google.co.uk"
    },{
        "cover": "highlighted/2.gif",
        "link":"http://google.com"
    }]
};
data.info.forEach(function(obj) {
    
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = obj.link;
    
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = obj.cover;
    
    link.appendChild(img);
    document.getElementById("img").appendChild(link);
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="cover" id="img"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Manipulating `DOM` within a loop is not a good practice when the manupulation is massive. In this case, you could make use of [DOM DocumentFragments](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) like below.

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

data.info.forEach(function(obj) {    
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = obj.link;
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = obj.cover;
    link.appendChild(img);
    fragment.appendChild(link);
});
//Append outside the loop all at once.
document.getElementById("img").appendChild(fragment);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use .each()**

```
$.each(data.info, function(i, val) {
      var src = val.cover;
      var link = val.link;
      $('a').attr('href', link)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `attr()` function to assign the href attribute:

```
 $('#anchor').attr('href', obj.link);
```

If you want to append a new element (`#holder` is the element in which the new element will get appended):

```
$('#holder').append('<a href="' + obj.link + '">LinkText</a>');
```